# Automatically merge one PR when a PR is merged in a different repository?

Tags: git, github, pull-request, circleci

Here's my use case:

1. I have two repos (call it repo A and B)
2. When I open a PR on repo A, CircleCI runs a tool on each changed file
3. The tool generates a new file for each changed file
4. The generated files are pushed into repo B
5. CircleCI (running on repo A) creates a PR on repo B with the changed files

The approval and merge of the PR on repo B is manual. What I want is to automatically merge the PR on repo A (where developers create PRs) when someone merges the PR on repo B.

Is this possible?

I thought about creating a small CircleCI pipeline on repo B to call that endpoint, but I'd like to know if there's a better way to do it.

Than you :)

Comment: We have a somewhat similar scenario, but we solved it differently: instead of paralleling the PR, what we have is that a push to `main` on A causes the artifacts to be generated and pushed to `main` on B at the same time. If you're not going to review that PR on B at all, there's no point in creating it as a PR, just commit and push the generated files once you know the PR is approved and pushed on `main` (or `release`, whatever your workflow is) on A.

Comment: A side benefit is that when the repo owner pushes a quick patch without going through a PR, B still gets updated.

Comment: We do need to manually review the PR on repo B :) so, unfortunately, that won't work

Comment: Darn, I was thinking that could be a reason to want a PR on B too, and almost asked if you did. But you might still be able to implement this as a CI workflow on push to main on A. You would need a test to recognize that it's a PR merge. If you name your PR branch on B carefully, you can clone B in the CI on A, merge the B-PR branch into B-main, and push that merge to B. That's the operation merging a PR does, you're just doing it remotely instead of doing it in the github UI.

Comment: Ya, I don't think there's another way. Thank you :)